# SPOJ giving wrong answer for this solution

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to solve [NGON](http://www.spoj.com/SPOJ/problems/NGON/) problem.  I am using bottom up dynamic programming here. Recurrence function is:

```
f(a,b) = f(a-1,b) + f(a-1,b-1)*ai +f(a-1,b-2)*ai*(ai-1)/2, a>0,b>0
f(a,0) = 1,
f(0,b) = 0,
```

ai being the points on ath side.

But I am getting Wrong Answer. I know it's hard to go through someone else's code but I truly appreciate any help. I feel I have taken care of overflows. Also please suggest if any optimizations are also possible.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 1010
#define MODULO 1000000007

int main()
{
    int test_cases,i,a,b;
    int sides,points[MAX];
    unsigned long long int result[MAX][MAX],temp;
    for(scanf("%d",&test_cases);test_cases>0;test_cases--)
    {
        scanf("%d",&sides);
        for(i=0;i<sides;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&points[i]);
        }

        result[0][0]=1;
        for(a=1;a<=sides;a++)
        {
            result[a][0]=1;
            result[0][a]=0;
        }

        for(a=1;a<=sides;a++)
        {
            for(b=1;b<=sides;b++)
            {
                if(b>2*a)
                {
                    result[a][b]=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    result[a][b]=(result[a-1][b]+result[a-1][b-1]*points[a-1])%MODULO;
                    if(b>1)
                    {
                        temp=(result[a-1][b-2]*points[a-1]*(points[a-1]-1))%MODULO;
                        temp=temp>>1;
                        result[a][b]=(result[a][b]+temp)%MODULO;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%lld\n",result[sides][sides-1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there may be a problem in these lines:

```
temp=(result[a-1][b-2]*points[a-1]*(points[a-1]-1))%MODULO;
temp=temp>>1;
```

The issue is that you need to take extra care when dividing when using modulo arithmetic.

For example, consider x/2 modulo 100.  This is not the same as x modulo 100 divided by 2.

Suppose x was 100,

```
x/2 % 100 = 100/2 % 100 = 50 % 100 = 50
```

but

```
(x % 100)/2 = (100%100)/2 = 0/2 = 0
```

Try doing the division before computing the modulo:

```
temp=(result[a-1][b-2]*((points[a-1]*(points[a-1]-1))>>1))%MODULO;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. GOT AC. Although I want to ask one more thing, is there any way to optimize the long long int and modulo calculations in some way to make it faster? I guess asymptotically algorithm limit is O(n^2).

Comment: It might help to precalculate the answer to (points[a-1]*(points[a-1]-1))>>1) for each value of a, and you could make b loop from 2 to min(sides,2*a) in order to take the conditional expressions out of the inner loop (although you would then have to add extra code before and after the loop to cope with the missing cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Precalculation helped. It improved running time of my code.